# PhoneGap ChildBrowser plugin with Android - Maintaining touches through view transitions

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, kendo-ui, childbrowser

I'm having a very strange problem with the PhoneGap ChildBrowser plugin for Android (also using Kendo UI framework from Telerik). If the ChildBrowser plugin is included in the project, any touches that last for more than a second are maintained through the transition to the next view. So, if I touch a button on page 1 that same touch is maintained and acted on on page 2 (which will then kick off any action on page 2 that corresponds to that touch location).

If I remove ChildBrowser it works fine. This happens on views that use the plugin and those that don't. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it should help anyone in the future - the bug had to do with Kendo UI, NOT ChildBrowser. (Fixed in latest version of Kendo!)